# Why doesn't FastAPI handle types derived from int and Enum correctly?

Tags: validation, fastapi, pydantic

With the following [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com) backend:

```py
from enum import Enum
from fastapi import FastAPI

class MyNumber(int, Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/add/{a}/{b}")
async def get_model(a: MyNumber, b: MyNumber):
    return {"sum": a + b}
```

When a `GET` operation is done:

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/add/2/3' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

Returns the following:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "a"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 1, 2, 3",
      "type": "type_error.enum",
      "ctx": {
        "enum_values": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "path",
        "b"
      ],
      "msg": "value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 1, 2, 3",
      "type": "type_error.enum",
      "ctx": {
        "enum_values": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is this the case? Even the Swagger UI does recognize the possible values as integers:

[image]

I have tried the solution of using `IntEnum` instead ([source](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2129)), and I can confirm that it works, but still - why does it have to be this way?

The [enum.py source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/enum.py) defines `IntEnum` as:

```py
class IntEnum(int, Enum):
    """Enum where members are also (and must be) ints"""
```

Comment: Because Enum can be anything, including not subclasses of int. That is why IntEnum exists, it ensures that it’s members are int or a subclass of int. As FastAPI doesn’t check what kind of member it is, it doesn’t just assume it’s a int. Use IntEnum in this case.

Comment: @JarroVGIT MyNumber is a subclass of int and Enum

Comment: Actually: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/enum.py states that IntEnum is defined as `class IntEnum(int, Enum)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did a little digging, based on the comments below OP. To start of with why this is not working as expected: it is how Starlette handles path parameters. When a request is handled by Starlette (or to be precise, when the `Router` object is called from which the `APIRouter` inherits), it determines the `path_params` as a dictionary with keys are parameter names and values as its value. However, when this happens and you haven't specified a type in the *path string*, it automatically treats the path parameters as string. It then adds this to the `Request`, basically as a dict `{"a":"1", "b":"2"}`. Then, further up the call stack, FastAPI is then trying to find the enum value corresponding to "1", which throws throws the validation error because `"1" is not 1`. Note that your `MyNumber` class does not play any role here yet.

This behaviour is by design and can be influenced like so:

```py
@app.get("/add/{a:int}/{b:int}")
```

This will make sure that Starlette will create a path_params dictionary like `{"a":1, "b":2}`. Note that `1` and `2` are now integers and will be handled as such by FastAPI.

As to why `MyNumber(IntEnum)` works out of the box while `MyNumber(int, Enum)` does not, that is a Pydantic implementation. I can't really seem to pinpoint how exactly, but when the `ModelField` is created for both parameters (which happens in `utils.py -> create_response_field()` upon application startup), the list of `validators` is including an `int` validator when using `IntEnum`.

But because `ModelField` is created using `functools.partial()` I cannot follow the call stack into Pydantic. So, I am unsure why this behaves like this.

So, in short, there are two options to fix this: either force Starlette to parse the path paramaters `a` and `b` as `int` (using `{a:int}`) or inherit from `IntEnum` in your own enum class.

Comment: I did some digging, too: In `pydantic/validators.py` there is the global `_VALIDATORS` which defines validators for each type. Seems like validators are just hardcoded for `IntEnum` to be an integer validator + enum validator, and the integer validator converts from string to int. This also means that a class `MyFloats(float, Enum)` as path parameter is also not possible (?), for example.

Comment: @JarroVGIT Please confirm that `{a:int}` is a working solution, as it doesn't seem to be. It leads to `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'MyNumber' and 'MyNumber'` error.

Comment: @Chris that definitely works. Don't forget to also change path param `b`, so full decorator is `@app.get("/add/{a:int}/{b:int}")`. I get a `{"sum": 3}` response when calling localhost:8000/add/1/2. See here for full working code: https://github.com/JarroVGIT/fastapi-github-issues/blob/master/SO/Enum_vs_IntEnum/app.py

Comment: I tested this on python 3.10.5, FastAPI 0.79 and uvicorn 0.18.2

Comment: It might have to do with Python version. Tested it on Python 3.8.6.

Comment: That's strange, as this is a documented Starlette feature: https://www.starlette.io/routing/#path-parameters I can't test it on that version (I am on apple silicon and first version with support was 3.8.10). Can confirm it working on 3.8.13 though.